# Websphere 8.5.5.16, OIDC IDToken - user problem

Tags: oauth, websphere, openid-connect

I'm trying to configure Oauth authorization on websphere 8.5.5.16. I added interceptor with issuerIdentifier parameter = https://company.com/abc I next step I added trust external realm: https://company.com/abc And when I try to start service in my app (IBM BPM) I getting an error: NullPointer Exception. Please look at the logs on how the user is created:

```
Principal: https://company.com/abc/login_user
Public Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.auth.WSCredentialImpl@ebc4e0d2
Private Credential: {setLtpaCookie=false, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.securityName=login_user, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.uniqueId=user:https://company.com/abc/login_user, token_type=, access_token=xxx, id_token=, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.realm=https://company.com/abc, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.groups=[], refresh_token=, JsonWebToken=JsonWebToken:{"aud":"0000","iss":"https://company.com/abc","iat":122,"nbf":123,"exp":232,"auth_time":222,"nonce":"aaa","sub":"ddddd/fffff","upn":"login_user","unique_name":"domain\\login_user","pwd_url":"https://company.com/abc/portal/updatepassword/","pwd_exp":"4545","sid":"S-1-5-21-66-117609710","authorities":["Group_1, Group_2"],"given_name":"Name","family_name":"Surname","apptype":"Public","appid":"0000","authmethod":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/windows","ver":"1.0","scp":"openid"}}
Private Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@347c9d2b
Private Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@718ea698
Private Credential: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@27e8a5bb


00000187 UserOrgModule 1 com.lombardisoftware.userorg.UserOrgModule getIdFromPrincipalName getIdFromPrincipalName() user=/company.com/abc/login_user, id=null
```

user = /company.com/abc/login_user not: login_user Why? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From message "00000187 UserOrgModule", I can tell your BPM application can not help realm name that contains '/' character. You can resolve the problem with following steps:

1. In your TAI properties, add useRealm property, and give an unique and meaningful value as realm, for example,
   provider_.useRealm=abc123
2. Add "abc123" as trusted realm. This value matches value you define in step 1.

If you assign roles to users unique id, you need reassign roles again with unique id build from this new realm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I did exactly as you wrote.

1. I added in my interceptor config: provider_1.useRealm=myrealm
2. I added trusted realm in Global security > Federated repositories > Trusted authentication realms - inbound (Name = myrealm, Trusted).
3. I restarted server.

Nothing has changed. I still see:  `user=/company.com/abc/login_user, id=null` because in JWT token, in iss field I have value: 'https://company.com/abc' and unfortunately I cannot change this